# Прижать footer к низу

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Подсобите пожалуйста с версткой начального макета на Bootstrap 4. Я не очень хороший верстальщик( Вот что я сделал:

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header class="container">
  HEADER
</header>
<main class="container">
  CONTENT
</main>
<footer class="container">
  FOOTER
</footer>
```

Вот видите что произошло? Футер ушел влево. :( Оно и понятно - `position: absolute`, но как по другому его прижать я не знаю. Можно задать сейчас `width: 100%`, но тогда он будет на всю ширину, а я хочу чтобы он был как и остальные блоки с отступами от краев. И еще мне не нравится то что блок `main` прилип к хедеру. Я хочу чтобы он разъезжался до футера даже без контента.

P.S. Может правильнее поставить класс `container` тегу `body`, а не всем по отдельности?

Comment: так стартовый макет bs не такой ..

Comment: @MaximLensky в смысле?

Comment: в смысле вот такой макет: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @MaximLensky во первых по этой ссылке нет макета, а только документация, во вторых макеты разные бывают - мне нужен такой, в третьих при чем тут столбцы, если я еще до них не дошел? Мне строки бы сверстать...

Comment: @MaximLensky мне нужно сверстать именно то что я объяснил в топике. Что вы мне в доку тыкаете? Я неплохо знаю бутстрап и без доки. Просто не знаю как футер правильно приделать.

Comment: очевидно вы плохо знаете bs...каждый css class в bs дубликат flexbox или css grid

Comment: @MaximLensky вам что заняться нечем? Вы или помогите сверстать или не выносите мне мозг бесполезными советами.

Comment: да блин - bs использует flex поищите в сети или здесь на so как прибить подвал к низу на flex это и будет ответ

Comment: @MaximLensky я не хочу разбираться как работает flexbox. Уже пробовал - для меня это слишком сложно. Мне нужно только сверстать начальный макет как я показал, а потом на бутстрапе я уже сделаю все что мне надо. Потому я им и пользуюсь что можно почти не зная CSS сверстать что угодно (за счет удобных модульных сеток).

Answer (score 5):

Изначально рекомендую ознакомиться с основами верстки и документацией по bootstrap.

1. [webref.ru](https://webref.ru/)
2. [webref.ru/layout/bootstrap4](https://webref.ru/layout/bootstrap4)
3. [getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/)

---

**Что не так в Вашем примере?!**

То что Вы просто задаете `footer` просто состояние `position: absolute`, а нужно дополнительно положение `top`, `left`. C расчетом, что подвал будет позиционироваться относительно `body` (либо ближайшего родителя с `position: relative`).

Если дополнительно задать еще и `right: 0`, то `footer` растянется на всю ширину контента (с учетом `max-width` и `margin: 0 auto;` у `container`).

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="container">
  HEADER
</header>
<main class="container">
  CONTENT
</main>
<footer class="container">
  FOOTER
</footer>
```

---

Но в bootstrap 4 уже все продумали для подобных случаев.

[Находим страницу о позиционировании в Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/)

И видим пример разметки для абсолютного позиционирования внизу страницы

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">...</div>
```

Итого:

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    HEADER
  </div>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</footer>
```

**Либо так:**

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    HEADER
  </div>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer position-absolute">
  <div class="container">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</footer>
```

С отступами, т.е. внутри `container` и контентом на всю высоту:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-warning">
  <header class="header fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bg-danger">
        HEADER
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="main h-100">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="bg-success h-100">
        CONTENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bg-primary">
        FOOTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Это конечно все хорошо, но вы потеряли отступы по бокам :( К тому же контент не растянулся до футера как я хотел

Comment: А теперь хедер перекрыл контент =(

Comment: @Hamster Красивый, развёрнутый и самое главное познавательный ответ )

Comment: @Denis640Kb, недостаточно, раз автору не помогло

Comment: @HamSter Мне кажется помогло ))) Просто промолчал. (У него много таких ответов) Вы абсолютно чётко и корректно не только показали как это сделать, но и объяснили, что именно и в каком формате делать. Несколько раз прочитал вопрос, посмотрел ответ. Ничего не перекрывается, если только пользователь сам не добавил дополнительно чего-либо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляйте и радуйтесь

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">fixed-bottom</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Документация](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#placement)

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer class="mt-auto position-sticky top-100">
   FOOTER
</footer>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]